# jQuery hover - button stays to be with hover effect

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover, release

```
$("#navigation li.active").next().hover(function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset -4px 0 7px -5px black");
});
```

When i release cursor from button, button stays with hover effect. Can you please to say how to make normal hover effect, which must be shown just when cursor is on button.

Comment: You can create a CSS class and use jQuery `toggleClass` method instead. `$(this).toggleClass('box-shadow')`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a mouse leave handler

```
$("#navigation li.active").next().hover(function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset -4px 0 7px -5px black");
}, function(){
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the second function available in hover():

```
$("#navigation li.active").next().hover(function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset -4px 0 7px -5px black");
} , 
function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "reset here. this is mouse out");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Jquery Docs of Hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

So,your one function executing for both the  events . You need to remove it after hover done

```
$("#navigation li.active").next().hover(
function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset -4px 0 7px -5px black");
},

 function() {
    //make your element normal here
   }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other guys' answers will work for you but actually it's much easier with css.

```
#navigation li:hover { box-shadow: inset -4px 0 7px -5px black; }
#navigation li.active:hover { box-shadow: none; }
```

If you must use javascript to do this, it's

```
$("#navigation li.active").next().hover(function() {
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "inset -4px 0 7px -5px black");
}, function(){
   $(this).css("box-shadow", "none");
});
```